# Javascript Sortable - evt.from shows [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, sortables

Using following on a web site to be able to drag elements from one column to another: https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable
It does not saves to database a new position of an item, to which column it was saved as it is written on Javascript.

Now my solution is per documentation to track when it was placed to another column with:

```
onEnd: function (evt) {
   alert(evt.from);
}
```

This will get from where it is moving:

```
Evt.from
```

Now, i am trying to alert it and it shows only:

```
[object HTMLDivElement]
```

How to convert it to html or how to show the data on Sortable correctly?

full code:

```
!function (t) {
    "use strict";
    t(document).ready(function () {
        t(".m-tasks__items").each(function () {
            Sortable.create(this, {
                group : ".m-tasks__items",
                sort : !0,
                handle : ".m-tasks__item-name",
                animation : 150,
                onEnd : function (evt) {
                    var r = evt.from;
                    //document.getElementById(evt.from).innerHTML;
                    console.log("Answer: " + evt.from);
                }
            })
        })
    })
} (jQuery);
```

Html:

```
<div class="main-container m-tasks__container container-heading-bordered">
    <h2 class="container-heading">
      <span>Tasks (3)</span>
      <span class="container-heading-controls">
        <a href="#" class="iconfont iconfont-action-plus container-heading-control"></a>
      </span>
    </h2>
    <div class="container-body m-tasks__columns">
      <div class="m-tasks__column m-tasks__column--new">
        <div class="m-tasks__column-header">
      <span class="m-tasks__column-icon iconfont iconfont-task-label"></span>
          <span class="m-tasks__column-name">Pending</span>
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block iconfont icon-left btn-lg m-tasks__add-card" type="button">
          Add new card <span class="btn-icon iconfont iconfont-plus"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="m-tasks__items m-tasks__column--new list-group">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="m-tasks__column m-tasks__column--in-progress list-group">
        <div class="m-tasks__column-header">
          <span class="m-tasks__column-icon iconfont iconfont-task-label"></span>
          <span class="m-tasks__column-name">In Progress</span>
        </div>
        <div class="m-tasks__items">
          No tasks         
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="m-tasks__column m-tasks__column--completed list-group">
        <div class="m-tasks__column-header">
          <span class="m-tasks__column-icon iconfont iconfont-task-label"></span>
          <span class="m-tasks__column-name">Completed</span>
        </div>
        <div class="m-tasks__items">
               <div class="m-tasks__item list-group-item" draggable="false" style="">
            <div class="dropdown no-arrow control-dropdown m-tasks__item-control">
              <span class="dropdown-toggle iconfont iconfont-dots" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" draggable="false">Edit</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" draggable="false">Delete</a>
                <div class="dropdown-text">Set priority:</div>
                <div class="dropdown-radios">
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-radio-simple custom-radio-simple--danger">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="radio">
                      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="custom-control-description">High</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-radio-simple custom-radio-simple--success">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="radio">
                      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="custom-control-description">Medium</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-radio-simple custom-radio-simple--secondary">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="radio" checked="">
                      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="custom-control-description">Normal</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <h6 class="m-tasks__item-name">Title 3</h6>
            <div class="m-tasks__item-desc">
             desc 3            </div>
            <span class="m-tasks__item-date">12-12-12</span>

                        <span class="m-tasks__item-priority iconfont iconfont-task-bell m-tasks__item-priority--medium"></span>
                      </div><div class="m-tasks__item list-group-item" style="">
            <div class="dropdown no-arrow control-dropdown m-tasks__item-control">
              <span class="dropdown-toggle iconfont iconfont-dots" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a>
                <div class="dropdown-text">Set priority:</div>
                <div class="dropdown-radios">
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-radio-simple custom-radio-simple--danger">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="radio">
                      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="custom-control-description">High</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-radio-simple custom-radio-simple--success">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="radio">
                      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="custom-control-description">Medium</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio custom-radio-simple custom-radio-simple--secondary">
                      <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" name="radio" checked="">
                      <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
                      <span class="custom-control-description">Normal</span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <h6 class="m-tasks__item-name">Title 2</h6>
            <div class="m-tasks__item-desc">
             desc 2            </div>
            <span class="m-tasks__item-date">12-12-12</span>

                        <span class="m-tasks__item-priority iconfont iconfont-task-bell m-tasks__item-priority--normal"></span>
                      </div>


        </div>
        <div class="m-tasks__empty-column">
          <img src="img/tasks/empty.png" alt="">
          <div class="m-tasks__empty-column-text">Drag items here or <br> <a href="#" class="link-info">Create New</a></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't use `alert()` as debugging tool, especially for objects. log it to the console

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it still says [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This post does  not make much sense without a more complete example. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Twisty thank you for your comment, added the full code now

Comment: Add some data attributes or ID's to the elements that are sortable so you can loop through them to get new order array

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your comment, but it still does not works

Comment: What doesn't work? That phrase is virtually meaningless

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry for being very short, I am just trying to figure out how does Sortable works. And I have added ids to the items and now the reply from Sortable still [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: You need to log things to the browser dev tools console...not alert. Did you create an array of the ID's in their new order and send it to server and make sure elements were displayed in that new order when page loads?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, and reply of the server is: [object HTMLDivElement]. Problem is that, the server only gets [object HTMLDivElement] instead of getting new order of IDs

Comment: @charlietfl this is not Jquery Sortable, but just Sortable javascript library which turns out to be not popular at all, hence there is no proper documentation or examples how it works. I will be moving on with Jquery Sortable as it is much easier.

Comment: you can't send whole elements. You have to extract the id's into array